# Migrate existing Django users to OpenLDAP with the same password

Tags: django, hash, openldap, migrate, pbkdf2

I'm using Django's User model as the authentication backend. Now I want to migrate all the users to an OpenLDAP server. I believe if I can make OpenLDAP use the same hashing algorithm and password string format, I can just copy over the password hash from Django, users will just be able to login using the same username and password when I plug in OpenLDAP.

My Django app's using PBKDF2 hasing algorithm so what I'm trying to do is to configure OpenLDAP to use PBKDF2 using this module: https://github.com/hamano/openldap-pbkdf2

The password hash in Django will be like:

pbkdf2_sha256$12000$MySaltString$somehashstring...

I tried many times but couldn't make it work with OpenLDAP.

It would be great if you guys could give me some hints.

Thanks a lot,

Trinh

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with python3, You can use salted mechanism provided on [ldap3 package on this page http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/standard.html](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/standard.html)

```
from ldap3 import HASHED_SALTED_SHA
from ldap3.utils.hashed import hashed

hashed_password = hashed(HASHED_SALTED_SHA, 'new_password')
connection.modify('cn=user1,o=test', {'userPassword': [(MODIFY_REPLACE,[hashed_password])]})
```

Comment: So if I'm right, your sample script is trying to update the user password to OpenLDAP. But, what I'm trying to do here is to copy the hashed password from my Django apps to OpenLDAP and then user can be authenticated from there.

Comment: At the time of user creation you can set the password in openLDAP, so there is no need to copy the password from your django app.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But i dont want to create new user. I want to migrate all of my users to OpenLDAP.